# Cython_VST_loader not installing through PIP

Tags: python, cython, anaconda3, vst

I am using anaconda3 with Python Version 3.8.

I followed the installation instructions for Cython VST loader per the package’s website (https://pypi.org/project/cython-vst-loader/).

This entailed:

- Updating Anaconda compiler (from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/compilers , 2nd line of code worked)
- PIP installing ‘make’ via Anaconda command line
- Not sure how to install/update headers, this may or may not be causing the error.

When I attempt to `pip install cython_vst_loader` in the command line, I receive the following deluge of errors.

[image: First Screenshot of Error]

[image: Second Screenshot of Error]

Any help or resources on how to address this problem would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: please copy paste the error message rather than screenshot

Comment: It looks like the makers of that package have hard-coded in some GCC-only command-line arguments. Therefore it's probably not going to work on MSVC and thus not going to work on Windows. It might be possible to work around it, but I'd treat it as unsupported.

Comment: I also think that https://pypi.org/project/make/ is different from the [`make` command](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)). You want to install the latter (which won't be through pip)

Comment: hi there. maintainer's here. The loader is, indeed, historically, linux-first, I wrote it primarily for this thing: https://github.com/hq9000/py_headless_daw, which is needed, again, for some linux-based products. 

Since I see some interest in the loader from windows users, I'm currently planning to spend some time on developing windows support. I'll let you know when something is ready. Or you can watch https://github.com/hq9000/cython-vst-loader/issues/10

Comment: hi all! Have just published 0.3.6 version with Windows support. Have also clarified some things about goals/scope/limitations of the loader https://github.com/hq9000/cython-vst-loader/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

With the new 0.3.6 version of the loader (released 15 minutes ago), Windows is supported and binaries are provided. Also, project goals are clarified in Readme, you might want to check them as well https://github.com/hq9000/cython-vst-loader/blob/master/README.md

You can install the new version normally with pip.